# How do you add NAME. to domain.com so you get NAME.domain.com and place in DNS?

Tags: url, dns

How do you create a name in a DNS such that you have a valid URL of NAME.domain.com?  I currently have an IP address assigned to domain.com.  I want to add a couple of more names. to my DNS so I have the following naming convention,

```
domain.com              IpAddr1
dev.domain.com          IpAddr2
qa.domain.com           IpAddr3
```

What is this type of naming convention called?  What does the DNS records look like?

Comment: Is your domain hosted or do you run your own DNS server? If you run your own server, what type and version is it?

Comment: I am using AWS and I use the AWS DNS.  We are running AWS Ubuntu LTS.

Comment: I think you need to consult with Amazon Web Services on how to configure your DNS for your domain. A common setup for most hosting providers these days is to give you a web interface to do it yourself. In there you would specify the settings you mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured this on out on my own.  What I was looking for was how to create a sub-domain name.  This is easy.  just take an existing domain name that you own and add a name in front of it.  An example would be dev.mydomain.com.  I can then go into a DNS server and create and A record with the new sub-domain name and a specific IP address.